# Casting HexNumber as character to string

Tags: c#, casting

I need to process a numeral as a string.

My value is `0x28` and this is the ascii code for `'('`.

I need to assign this to a string.

The following lines do this.

```
char c = (char)0x28;
string s = c.ToString();

string s2 = ((char)0x28).ToString();
```

My usecase is a function that only accepts strings.
My call ends up looking cluttered:

```
someCall( ((char)0x28).ToString() );
```

Is there a way of simplifying this and make it more readable without writing `'('` ?

The Hexnumber in the code is always paired with a Variable that contains that hex value in its name, so "translating" it would destroy that visible connection.

Edit:

A List of tuples is initialised with this where the first item has the character in its name and the second item results from a call with that character.

One of the answers below is exactly what i am looking for so i incorporated it here now.

```
{ existingStaticVar0x28, someCall("\u0028") }
```

The reader can now instinctively see the connection between item1 and item2 and is less likely to run into a trap when this gets refactored.

Comment: Your sample code (and problem text) doesn't really show why you can't simply do `someCall("(")`. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Alex:i edited my posting to elaborate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Unicode character escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in place of a hex to avoid casting:

```
string s2 = '\u28'.ToString();
```

or

```
someCall("\u28");
```

Answer (score 2):

Well supposing that you have not a fixed input then you could write an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

```
namespace MyExtensions
{
    public static class MyStringExtensions
    {
        public static string ConvertFromHex(this string hexData)
        {
            int c = Convert.ToInt32(hexCode, 16);
            return new string(new char[] {(char)c});
        }
    }
}
```

Now you could call it in your code wjth

```
string hexNumber = "0x28"; // or whatever hexcode you need to convert
string result = hexNumber.ConvertFromHex();
```

A bit of error handling should be added to the above conversion.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ConvertHexToString`?

Comment: Oh wait, naming is always the most difficult part. What about ConvertFromHex? It is a string after all.

Comment: Whichever you see fit. I just found `string result = hexNumber.ConvertHexToChar` odd as it returns a `string` :)